# Instantiate an stdClass object from json schema specification in PHP

Tags: php, json, rest

I have a set of JSON requests that I must send to a RESTFul API in order to get some response objects, you know, the usual thing for a webapp, however these API request objects are properly documented with a json schema specification for each, so I would like to load those schema files and create stdClass object instances based on that info *automagically*.

Is there some way to do this with a library or something in PHP? (don't want to reinvent the wheel)

Thanks!

**Edit:** Have a look at [this schema file](https://github.com/tangocarddev/RaaS/blob/master/account_create.schema.json) which contains an example of what I want to load and build object instances from.

***Disclaimer:*** I do know [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) / [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) which is not what I'm looking for. Using that I'd need to traverse through the returned schema object and then create another object/array based on the schema read, which is not what I want.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `json_decode` already returns `stdClass` objects.

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/tangocarddev/RaaS/blob/master/account_create.schema.json

that's the schema for an object, it defines it. I want to load that json somehow and be able to create instances based on that schema.

Comment: What is the fixation with `stdClass` then? You can just have this as arrays and serialize to JSON. This schema looks very complex (in terms of validation), there is (to my knowledge) no standard function that can do this for you. If you relaxed the demands on the input (like the regexps) you _could_ write an instance generator. As it is your problem boils do to: _how can I generate a string that matches this regexp?_ Which is very hard to solve.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I have no fixation whatsoever, I just don't want to do it myself if there was something already. In the end I just might end, like you said, serializing and traversing and creating instances based on the properties defined there

Comment: Would you agree that "Generate valid instance for schema" would be a better question description?

Comment: are you saying you want to take the schema file and then instantiate an empty stdClass object?

Comment: @watcher Yeah, an empty one based on that schema

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built-in way of doing this, but it should be relatively trivial to implement:

```
function createObj( $json ) {
    $obj_schema = json_decode($json, true);
    $new_obj = new StdClass;
    foreach($obj_schema['properties'] as $property) {
      $new_obj->{$property} = null;
    }

    return $new_obj;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing right now!, great minds think alike :)